# Reverse heterogeneous gadt list with recursively dependent elements

Tags: ocaml, reverse, gadt, heterogeneous-list

Having seen [this answer about the elements of a List that depend on the type of preceding elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71693060/is-it-possible-to-have-elements-of-a-heterogeneous-list-depend-on-the-type-of-pr) , where the problem was solved with the following list definition:

```ml
 type ('a,'b) mlist =
  | MNil : ('a,'a) mlist
  | MCons : ('a, 'b) element * ('b,'c) mlist -> ('a,'c) mlist
```

where an "element" is :

```ml
module Tag = struct
  type root = Root
  type fruit = Fruit
  (* ... *)
end
type (_,_) element=
  | Fruit : (Tag.root, Tag.fruit) element
  | Veggie : (Tag.root, Tag.veggie) element
  (* ... and so on *)
```

I find it really useful for creating a list where you want to have some rules about the order of elements. For example when creating a list of layers in a neural network...

**I now want to reverse this list.** So I have defined a new reversed list type like this:

```ml
 type ('a,'b) rev_list =
  | RNil : ('a,'a) rev_list
  | RCons : ('b, 'c) element * ('a,'b) rev_list -> ('a,'c) rev_list
```

where the last element's type depends on the previous one.

But I have a trouble with the reverse function :

```ml
let rec rev : type a b c. (a, c) mac_list ->
                    (b, a) rev_list ->
                    (c, b) rev_list =
  fun lst acc -> 
  match lst with
  | MNil -> acc (* <- error *)
  | MCons (h, t) ->
     revp t (RCons (h, acc))
```

Obviously, Ocaml complains that the return type does not match the type of accumulator:
type (b, a) is not compatible with type (c, b) ...

However if I write `(b, a) rec_list` as a return type, I get an error on the last line (on recursive function call) because, obviously, the type of the previous list element in the `acc` is not the same as the one that I add right now.

And I don't think I can use any existential wrappers here as (afaik) I would lose the type information about list elements...

Although the code is in Ocaml I would be happy if you have a solution in Haskell or at least some advice where can I search for it..

If you have any idea on how it is possible to restrict the order of elements in a list or maybe some other data structure, knowing that I also need to iterate through it backwards, I would be grateful to know.

**EDIT:**
Looks like I oversimplified the problem to post it here, my bad.
But what if the original problem looks like this:
I actually have `mlist` and `rev_list` defined like so:

```ml
type ('a,'b) mac_list =
  | MNil : ('a,'a) mlist
  | MCons : ('a, 'b) element * (('b,'c) element, _) mlist -> 
            (('a,'c) element, 'e) mlist

type ('a,'b) rev_list =
  | RNil : ('a,'a) rev_list
  | RCons : ('b, 'c) element * (('a,'b) element, _) rev_list ->
            (('a,'c) element, 'e) rev_list
```

I'm not sure if those definitions make sense, but I really need the information about the types inside an "element" to iterate through the list as I want to pass the "fruit" or "vegie" of the current element to the next iteration.

My iteration code which works fine until I want to reverse the list:

```ml
(* ... *)
type (_,_) element=
  | Fruit : Tag.root -> (Tag.root, Tag.fruit) element
 (* ... *)

let rec iter : type a b c. ((a, b) element, c) mlist -> a 
               -> unit =
  fun list input ->
  match list with
  | MNil -> ()
  | MCons (element, tail) ->
     (match element with
      | Fruit root ->
         (* processing the input *)
         let fruit : Tag.fruit = (* to fruit *) root + input in 
         iter tail fruit
     (* ... *) )
```

And the `rev` function is now as follows:

```ml
let rec rev : type a b c d. ((b, c) element, d) mlist ->
                    ((a, b) element, _) rev_list ->
                    ((a, c) element, _) rev_list =
  fun lst acc -> 
  match lst with
  | MNil -> acc 
  | MCons (h, t) ->
     rev t (RCons (h, acc))
```

In this case I keep getting an error on returning an accumulator no matter the order of types...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are one typo away from the solution,
let's first rewrite the type of your `rev` function with more explicit types:

```
let rec rev : type bottom current top.
  (current, top) mlist ->
  (bottom, current) rev_list ->
  (top, bottom) rev_list =
  fun lst acc ->
  match lst with
  | MNil -> acc (* <- error *)
  | MCons (h, t) ->
     rev t (RCons (h, acc))
```

If you look closely at the type of the two `rev_list`s, there is something strange in the order of their parameter: the intermediary list is a `(bottom, current) rev_list` thus preserving the order `bottom -> top` at the type system while, the result is a `(top, bottom) rev_list` which reverse the order of the type parameters.

There is an inconsistency here which is not that surprising since the two choices are valid in function of the definition of `rev_list`. In your case, you have:

```ml
type ('a,'b) rev_list =
  | RNil : ('a,'a) rev_list
  | RCons : ('b, 'c) element * ('a,'b) rev_list -> ('a,'c) rev_list
```

whereas the other choice would be

```ml
type ('a,'b) rpath =
  | RPNil : ('a,'a) rpath
  | RPCons : ('b, 'a) element * ('b,'c) rpath -> ('a,'c) rpath
```

Notice that your choice preserves the direction of the element of the list whereas the second one reverse it.

Thus you have chosen at the start that the reverse of `('a,'b) mlist` will be ('a,'b) rev_list`and not`('b,'a) rev_list`.

In other words, to fix your function we just need to remember this choice consistently and make the return type `(bottom,top) rev_list` rather than
`(top,bottom) rev_list`:

```
let rec rev : type bottom current top.
  (current, top) mlist ->
  (bottom, current) rev_list ->
  (bottom, top) rev_list =
  fun lst acc ->
  match lst with
  | MNil -> acc
  | MCons (h, t) ->
     rev t (RCons (h, acc))
```

Comment: Ok, I see. I actually oversimplified the problem to post it here, my bad. I now edited the original question with somewhat pretty close to the problem I have (of course I don't have fruits and veggies in my code). Please tell me if you find it possible to reverse list as in updated question. Thank you.

Comment: Your definition of `mlist` is really suspicious: you are moving the meaningful type parameters under the `element` constructor which shouldn't change anything for an injective constructor while breaking the type equality on the `MNil` case. I would suggest that you ask a separate question with your original iteration problem to start at the root issue rather than a derived issue.